# Moving Google Firebase Project from Old PC to New PC

Tags: windows, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I had configured my old laptop with firebase-cli to upload my website to Google Cloud Hosting.
Now I got the new laptop and trying to configure the new laptop with firebase-cli. I have installed all required tools for firebase. I transferred the source code from my old laptop to new laptop.

But when I try to deploy code from new laptop by using following command:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:myfirstproject
```

there is an error that myproject is not found in firebase.json

I changed firebase.json from myproject to myfirstproject.

but it is still not working.

I tried using the following command

```
firebase -P project-id init hosting
```

This command responds that make sure you have permission to access it.

Can someone guide what is to be done for moving project from old pc to new pc.
Thanks.

I changed firebase.json file as per project name showing in google console. but it is not working and giving the same error that myproject is not in firebase.json

Answer (score 0):

After Lot of testing, I am able to resolve my issue. There was an error that myproject was listed in firebase.json.
So, I made changes to firebase.json outside "public" directory of my project.
I added
"site": "myproject",
to my firebase.json and restarted the laptop.
Then issued command
firebase deploy --only hosting:myproject
and
It worked flawlessly.
Thanks everyone.